# LM317 burns adj resistor

Tags: lm317

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHWQkK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm building an LM317 power supply circuit along with some capacitors.

It works great until I turn the potentiometer down. When I do this the ADJ resistor will burn out or the potentiometer will smoke.

I'm using a 240 ohm resistor for the adjustment terminals. The only thing I can figure is that the current is just too high for both. Can anyone help?

Comment: schematic required

Comment: "*Can anyone help?*" Probably not without a schematic. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please click on edit and the schematic symbol and show how you have connected everything.

Comment: we need that schematic to help, but, as a hint, a potentiometer has a maximum **current** specification which is independent of the wiper position. You can calculate that current by taking the power specification for the full scale resistance. To put it another way, the power handling of a pot falls as the resistance is turned down , because there's less active track area to dissipate the heat.

Comment: What Peter Bennet said PLUS R2 has a maximum value as it is used to provide operating current for the LM317. As you had it connected you were "starving" the IC of operating current.

Answer (score 3):

You have connected the resistor network incorrrectly - it should be like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRdxeU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LM317 tries to keep the voltage between the output and adjust pins at 1.25 volts.

Comment: Thanks ill pull out the bread board and act upon this drawing.